# Why have I not received my newsletters yet?

Tags: support, newsletter

I subscribed to 4 newsletters which are StackOverflow, Christianity, Beer and Meta SE one week ago, but I haven't received these newsletters yet. Why?

Comment: got lost in the mail....

Comment: Did you confirm the subscription? To prevent possible abuse, the system first sends email with subject like "Email Verification - [site name]" and only after you click "Click here to verify your email address" in the email body will you start getting the newsletters.

Comment: I noticed that you're subscribed to more newsletters, so does it mean for the others you get them without a problem?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I subscribed more newsletters today. Before that, I subscribed 4 newsletters. Does the subscription need confirmation? Maybe not. The newsletters may be treated as spam. I will try to find it.

Comment: Yes you must confirm before they are being sent, you probably missed the confirmation email. You can re-send it from [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/5869035/xshsinap?tab=subscriptions), by clicking the "resend confirmation" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These mails were treated as spam and find them out. If it happened, you should add "do-not-reply@stackexchange.com" to the white list of your email.

Comment: And how exactly this answers the question? "Maybe", "try"?

Comment: If you mean you discovered the emails were treated as spam and handled it, you really better edit the answer to make it clear.

Comment: Better now - if you can also add what email provider you have and steps to find/unblock future email it would turn the answer to a good shape.

Comment: OK. I have edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent abuse, one must first confirm his/her email address in order to have the newsletters really be sent.

When subscribing, a confirmation email is being sent automatically, with such subject:

> Email Verification - [site name]

Which contains in the body a link "Click here to verify your email address", and once clicked you will start getting the newsletters for that site.

In case the confirmation email was lost, you can resend it by going to [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) subscriptions tab, and in there you'll see a "resend confirmation" link:

> [image]

Comment: I haven't received the confirmation email and I just received the welcome email. And I don't see the "resend confirmation" link. Are you sure it is about newsletter?

Comment: Yes I am sure. You are probably not logged in to the network profile. See in the top bar, you will have "log in" link then when logged in, you will see the "resend" link.